# Requirements for LastUpdate timestamp on Sabre Profiles

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to update a sabre Profile using Sabre_OTA_ProfileUpdateRQ. I get the error message

```
Invalid Last Update Time Stamp. Profile probabaly has been updated by another client
```

I've tried sending the "last modified" date on the profile on our side, as well as the "last sync with Sabre" timestamp. Both result in the same error message. What are the requirements for this field?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the two timestamps must exactly match the ones stored in Sabre. (read: match whatever is returned in Sabre_OTA_ProfileReadRS